# How to access passport user on client side?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-local, passport.socketio

I have used [passport local strategy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-local) to authenticate the user and used [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) as sessionstore module to save **passport/express sessions** in *mongodb* and I integrated 
[passport.socketio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport.socketio) and authorized the user using

```
  io.use(passportSocketIo.authorize({
  cookieParser: cookieParser,             
  secret:       'sessionSecret',    
  store:        sessionStore,        
  success:      onAuthorizeSuccess,  
  fail:         onAuthorizeFail,     
  }));
```

from **onAuthorizeSuccess** function i consoled logged **data.user** which was from passport.Now I can access the data on the server.
But how do I access the **req.user** that is **passport user** **on client the side.**

the **data.user** gives the same result as **req.user**

```
 function onAuthorizeSuccess (data,accept){
      console.log("data from socket: "+data.user);
      console.log('successful connection to socket.io');
}
```

**My client side code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000/chat");
    socket.on('connect', function () {

    //how to access passport user here 

       console.log("connection establised");
    });
});
```

**My server side code**

```
module.exports = function (io) {
    var chat = io.of("/chat").on("connection", function () {
        console.log("connection established on the server");
    });
};
```

Comment: When `socket.on('connect')` is successful, you send a get request to the server. Then server send response with the user's (`req.user`) data.

Comment: @AtaurRahimChowdhury Hopefully the asker found your comment useful in which case you should convert it into an answer so that they can accept it and mark this question solved.